# Negative performance implications of using GWT emulated stack trace

Tags: gwt

For ease of reporting client side GWT issues, the emulated stack trace is very valuable.
However when I activate this feature, there are serious performance implications (I've had to back it out twice now)

Specifically, it has been observed that while the GWT application is being downloaded, the IE browser appears to freeze and do nothing for 15 seconds or more when the emulated stack trace feature is enabled.

Has anyone else experienced this, and if so were you able to resolve the performance issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At compile time, generate permutations for both native and emulated stack traces in *.gwt.xml:
`<set-property name="compiler.stackMode" value="native,emulated" />`

At run time, make your selection, e.g.
`<meta name="gwt:property" content="compiler.stackMode=emulated" />`

Comment: So, in production, I assume you'd choose native?

Comment: Yes, we deploy with native, and edit the meta tag in the jsp that delivers the GWT application as necessary to temporarily switch to emulated (just long enough to recreate a problem, then switch it back to native)

Comment: @wytten How do you do the switch back to native? What does native means?

Comment: @confile Native is the default stack mode.  The set-property tag in gwt.xml tells the compiler to generate both native and emulated.  In the page that loads the application, if there is no meta tag that sets the stack mode to emulated then it defaults to native.  So in our source code the meta tag shown in the answer above is commented out.  After the application deploys, the page can be edited in the deployed image to uncomment the meta tag and thereby switch to emulated temporarily.